# sfDoctrineAplly plugin mailing

Tags: macos, symfony1, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer, mailing

I ose symfony 1.4.11 and sfDoctrineApply plugin. When user register,or change his password, he get an email. In debuger I see next:

```
    Configuration
Delivery strategy: none 
Email sent
Please verify your password reset request on www.somesite.com (to: d@gmail.com) 
Message-ID: <1306213078.4ddb3ad6b06a2@somesite.com>
Date: Tue, 24 May 2011 06:57:58 +0200
Subject: Please verify your password reset request on gi.wir-entwickeln.de
From: Global Invest <no-reply@somesite.com>
To: Herr D <d@gmail.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_13062130784ddb3ad6b596d_=_"

--_=_swift_v4_13062130784ddb3ad6b596d_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


Nous avons re=C3=A7u votre demande de r=C3=A9cup=C3=A9ration d'ide=
ntifiant et peut-=C3=AAtre =C3=A9galement de mot de passe sur http://gi.wi=
r-entwickeln.de

Dein Username: admin@gmail.com

Wenn = du dein Passwort vergessen hast oder es zur=C3=BCcksetzen m=C3=B6chtest, d=
ann klicke auf den folgenden Link:

http://somesite.com/f=
rontend_dev.php/confirm/r12cfba1527352e1e

Du wirst aufgefordert=
 dein neues Passwort anzugeben.

Dein Passwort wir nicht g=
e=C3=A4ndert, solange du nicht auf den oberen Link klickst und das Formul=
ar ausf=C3=BCllst.

--_=_swift_v4_13062130784ddb3ad6b596d_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p>
Nous avons re=C3=A7u votre demande de r=C3=A9cup=C3=A9ration d'i=
dentifiant et peut-=C3=AAtre =C3=A9galement de mot de passe sur <a hre=
f=3D"http://gi.wir-entwickeln.de">gi.wir-entwickeln.de</a>
</p><p>=

Dein Username: admin@gmail.com
</p><p>
Wenn du dein Pass=
wort vergessen hast oder es zur=C3=BCcksetzen m=C3=B6chtest, dann klicke a=
uf den folgenden Link:
</p><p>
<a href=3D"http://somesite.com/frontend_dev.php/confirm/r12cfba1527352e1e">http://somesite.com/frontend_dev.php/confirm/r12cfba1527352e1e</a>
</p><p>
D=
u wirst aufgefordert dein neues Passwort anzugeben.
</p><p>
Dein =
Passwort wir nicht ge=C3=A4ndert, solange du nicht auf den oberen Link kl=
ickst und das Formular ausf=C3=BCllst.
</p>


--_=_swift_v4_13062130784ddb3ad6b596d_=_--
```

And user get email. I have no problem with gmail or TheBat. But standart program "Email" on the MAC get letters that contains text same as I see in debuger...Is this problem of sfDoctrineApplyPlugin, or this is a problem of "Email" program? Thank you!

Comment: Most probably with your client, the mail looks fine - boundaries are OK, content-transfer-encoding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write text/html instead of text/plain , and all are ok:)